# Modelling an S-shaped Second Order Response

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

I am trying to model an [S-shaped second order process response](https://www.picontrolsolutions.com/papers/step-less-closed-loop-multivariable-transfer-function-system-identification-the-slic-id-algorithm/) as a transfer function in Simulink, as shown in [Figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCPgL.png) in the linked article. Ideally the response should be overdamped. I have tried using the function: $\frac{1}{s^2 + 5s + 1}$
however my process response is non-S shaped. Could you please give me advise on how to adjust my transfer function such that it emulates the figure in the article?

Comment: I think you are looking for a logistic curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

Comment: @EthanBolker yes, thank you. However, I would like to model this (or similar) as a time domain function such that I can produce a logistic curve in response to a step input.

Comment: Try $\frac{1}{(s + 1)^n}$ for $4 \leq n \leq 10$, that should be similar to your image. But the question is quite vague because "S-shaped" is not a precisely defined thing.

Comment: Maybe this will help you get a better understanding of how to choose the polynomial in the denominator. https://www.et.byu.edu/~tom/classes/436/ClassNotes/Class20(Second-Order).pdf

On slide 1 they give you the general form of a second-order system and on slide two they give you the conditions.